# FilterHeader not working with modelfield type object

Tags: javascript, c#, extjs4.2, ext.net

I'm having problem with my filter header on grids that loads ModelFiled with type object, that means when I have an object as an Index and render the columnsvalues with javascript Render Handler and then try to filter in the grid with these columns the filter dose not work. 
Any idea to fix this?

Some code:

```
<ext:Store ID="id">
    <Model><ext:ModelField Name="Endpoints" Type="Object" /></Model>
</ext:store>
<ColumnModel ID="ColumnModel_Users" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <ext:Column ID="ColumnEndpointName" runat="server" DataIndex="Endpoints" Text="EndpointName">                                               <Renderer Handler="return value.EndpointName" />
        </ext:Column>
    </Columns>
</ColumnModel>
```

Comment: Strange that the code is missing the Renderer: <ext:Column ID="ColumnEndpointName" runat="server" DataIndex="Endpoints" Text="<%$ Lang: EndpointName %>">
            <Renderer Handler="return value.EndpointName" />
           </ext:Column>

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Andreas if you read my coment that explains what happens here, that might be a bugg, the code tags aren't working as they should

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the solution and it was that I the modelfield with a convert handler so that data been rendered as if it is a normal column like String or what so ever:

```
 <ext:ModelField Name="EndpointName">
     <Convert Handler="return record.data.Endpoints ? record.data.Endpoints.EndpointName : '';" />
</ext:ModelField>
<ext:Column ID="ColumnEndpointName" runat="server" DataIndex="EndpointName" Text="EndpointName"  Flex="1" />
```

Hope it will help you ;-)